# getline() is repeatedly reading the file, when fork() is used

Tags: c, linux, fork

I am developing a simple shell program, a command line interpreter and I wanted to read input from the file line by line, so I used getline() function. At the first time, the program works correctly, however, when it reaches the end of the file, instead of terminating, it starts to read a file from the start and it runs infinitely.
Here are some codes in main function that are related to getline():

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int const IN_SIZE = 255;
    char *input = NULL;
    size_t len = IN_SIZE;
    // get file address
    fileAdr = argv[2];

    // open file
    srcFile = fopen(fileAdr, "r");

    if (srcFile == NULL) {
        printf("No such file!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (getline( &input, &len, srcFile) != -1) {
        strtok(input, "\n");
        printf("%s\n", input);
        // some code that parses input, firstArgs == input
        execSimpleCmd(firstArgs);            
    }
    fclose(srcFile);
}
```

I am using fork() in my program and most probably it causes this problem.

```
void execSimpleCmd(char **cmdAndArgs) {

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        // error
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
        exit(-1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // child process
        if (execvp(cmdAndArgs[0], cmdAndArgs) < 0) {
            printf("There is no such command!\n");
        }
        exit(0);
    } else {
        // parent process
        wait(NULL);
        return;
    }
}
```

In addition, sometimes the program reads and prints a combinations of multiple lines. For example, if an input file as below:

```
ping
ww    
ls
ls -l
pwd
```

it prints something like pwdg, pwdww, etc. How to fix it?

Comment: Please consolidate your code quotes into a [mcve].

Comment: I am always getting suspicious about lines like `// some code that parses input, firstArgs == input`

Comment: Your `execSimpleCmd` is almost the same as the `system` command. What if you use it instead? What if you *don't* use it at all and just have some stub?

Comment: Detail: `execvp()` only returns on failure.  Corollaries: (1) there's no need to test the return value; (2) it is better to report errors on `stderr` than `stdout`; (3) it is better to exit with an error status such as `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or variations on the theme of `exit(127);` etc — see POSIX for the details of what's recommended.  Also note that the child process should close the file so that the executed program can't screw things up.

Comment: Protip: copy the code from your post into a new file, compile/run it, and verify that it still produces the same error you write about. This is how you ensure that your question contains all relevant details. If you instead post pseudo-code roughly equivalent to what you run, you'll often end up leaving out important details that make all the difference

Comment: I think the problem here is that you are forking and doing execvp when it is sufficient to just do one. Both commands spawn a new process

Comment: @smac89  No. Only `fork` does.

Comment: I spoke too soon, looks like execvp replaces the current process, which makes sense why you fork

Comment: I don't know why, but removing the `else` part in your code makes it to run to completion. The reason for removing the else has to do with the fact that each child process `exits` after it runs the command, so there is really nothing to wait for...

Comment: However, I don't know why removing the wait part causes it not to infinitely loop as it did before

Comment: The code cannot be compiled as posted, because essential parts like `#include` directives and declarations are omitted.

Comment: By the way, you never close your file. Each `fork` is duplicating the file descriptor and it remains open in that child process.

Comment: Here is an MVC if anyone wants to test this:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/FwUHnH5YPwUDeYmC

Comment: When I remove the exit command for the child process and put back the wait in the parent, it also allows the program to complete...

Comment: @smac89 Your example works for me with both `exit` and `wait`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's interesting. On my machine it doesn't work, but online it does...My kernel version is 4.15, but the online machine is running version 4.4. I wonder if that makes a difference

Comment: Waaaait. Are you seeing the output from `printf("%s\n", input);` several times and thinking that it is because of the loop running more than it should? I would say it's because of IO buffering, while the buffer is duplicated by `fork`.

Comment: Anyway, looks like the OP have abandoned this question and we are wasting time here.

Comment: @EugeneSh. you're right, OP has left the chat. Anyways, what I mean is that all the commands in the file seem to be repeatedly running, not just the printf commands; And I have to manually Ctrl + C to exit. I think this is what OP meant as well

Comment: The program is working correctly if there is no non-existing command in the input file.

Comment: @EugeneSh even if I remove prinf part, the program infinitely runing

Comment: You are closing the input file after each call to `execSimpleCmd()`, and then trying to read from that file again.  This constitutes a definite error, with accompanying undefined behavior, though I cannot be certain that it is responsible for your specific observations.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah.. that's probably it, missed this line completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that closing a `FILE` in some cases seeks the underlying file descriptor back to the position where the application actually read to, effectively undoing the effect of the read buffering. This matters, since the OS level file descriptors of the parent and the child point to the same *file description*, and the same file offset in particular.

The [POSIX description of `fclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/fclose.html) has this phrase:

> [CX] [Option Start] If the file is not already at EOF, and the file is one capable of seeking, **the file offset of the underlying open file description shall be set to the file position of the stream** if the stream is the active handle to the underlying file description.

(Where [CX means an extension to the ISO C standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/help/codes.html#CX), and `exit()` of course runs `fclose()` on all streams.)

I can reproduce the odd behavior with this program (on Debian 9.8):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *f;
    if ((f = fopen("testfile", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    int right = 0;
    if (argc > 1)
        right = 1;

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    // first line 
    getline(&line, &len, f);
    printf("%s", line);

    pid_t p = fork();
    if (p == -1) {
        perror("fork");
    } else if (p == 0) {
        if (right)
            _exit(0);  // exit the child 
        else
            exit(0);   // wrong way to exit
    } else {
        wait(NULL);  // parent
    }

    // rest of the lines
    while (getline(&line, &len, f) > 0) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

Then:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\nc\n' > testfile
$ gcc -Wall -o getline getline.c
$ ./get
getline   getline2  
$ ./getline
a
b
c
b
c
```

Running it with `strace -f ./getline` clearly shows the child seeking the file descriptor back:

```
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f63794e0710) = 25117
strace: Process 25117 attached
[pid 25116] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 25117] lseek(3, -4, SEEK_CUR)      = 2
[pid 25117] exit_group(1)               = ?
```

(I didn't see the seek back with a code that didn't involve forking, but I don't know why.)

So, what happens is that the C library on the main program reads a block of data from the file, and the application prints the first line. After the fork, the child exits, and seeks the fd back to where the application level file pointer is. Then the parent continues, processes the rest of the read buffer, and when it's finished, it continues reading from the file. Because the file descriptor was seeked back, the lines starting from the second are again available.

In your case, the repeated `fork()` on every iteration seems to result in an infinite loop.

Using `_exit()` instead of `exit()` in the child fixes the problem *in this case*, since `_exit()` only exits the process, it doesn't do any housekeeping with the stdio buffers.

With `_exit()`, any output buffers are also not flushed, so you'll need to call `fflush()` manually on `stdout` and any other files you're writing to.

However, if you did this the other way around, with the child reading and buffering more than it processes, then it would be useful for the child to seek back the fd so that the parent could continue from where the child actually left.

Another solution would be not to mix `stdio` with `fork()`.

Comment: Note that `exit` is only called in the child if `execvp` fails -- if it succeeds, it never returns.  Still it is usual to `_exit` rather than `exit` after a failed exec for precisely the reasons you describe.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, hmm yeah, you're right. That's what I get for trying to reduce the problem too much, d'oh. If the `exec` succeeds, the stdio buffers will get thrashed and there's no cleanup, at least directly from what the parent did. Though I suppose what happens then depends on what the `exec`'d process does, not that I was smart enough to test that. In to the trashcan this answer goes, I think.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks. I replaced exit() with _exit(), and for my test cases, the program worked correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Four years later, here I am in the same boat with OP wondering why my parent input stream is rewinding when my child _exec()_ fails. The POSIX 2018 standard doesn't cross reference _fclose()_ in the description of _exit()_, just says open streams are flushed and closed. The connection you made is critical to actually understanding the behavior of _exit()_ and should be incorporated into the POSIX standard.