# Simple fork() program

Tags: c++, fork

I am trying to make a program that checks a list of steam servers using fork. I saw that if i put 100.000 lines servers often the program goes in a wired loop and checks the same servers over and over and over again. After a debug i see that even a simple program that prints the server ip goes unexpected.

**Program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    puts("Beginning program");

    int max_forks = 500;
    int num_forks = 0;

    FILE *fpxxx = fopen("servers", "r");
    if(fpxxx == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to open file!");
        exit(0);
    }

    char chunk[128];

    while(fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk), fpxxx) != NULL)
    {
        // puts(chunk); // same result if put the line here

        if(!(fork()))
        {
            // sleep(3);
            puts(chunk);

            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            num_forks++;

            if (num_forks >= max_forks)
            {
                wait(NULL);
                num_forks--;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fpxxx);
    sleep(10);
}
```

**Output :**

```
Beginning forking
94.xxx.xxx.209

Beginning forking
184.xxx.xxx.117

Beginning forking
108.xxx.xxx.86

Beginning forking
178.xxx.xxx.140

Beginning forking
113.xxx.xxx.132

Beginning forking
45.xxx.xxx.16

... (many lines, thus servers.txt has 100.000+ ips)

# after a while i see
Beginning forking
178.xxx.xxx.140
# again and again and again


# sometimes i even see
Beginning forking
37.247.104.933.17.199.143
```

Expected output :

```
94.xxx.xxx.209
184.xxx.xxx.117
108.xxx.xxx.86
178.xxx.xxx.140
113.xxx.xxx.132
45.xxx.xxx.16
```

Do i forget something? Seems like the heap is corrupted. And why i see `Beginning forking` as if the program runs again from the begining? I know that forking is making another process but I though that `fork()` forks the program from the point where `fork()` is.

Thank you.

**EDIT** : solution is [getline() is repeatedly reading the file, when fork() is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912662/getline-is-repeatedly-reading-the-file-when-fork-is-used)

Comment: You're forking your process 100,000 times??? This is... wrong...

Comment: Can your OS even handle 100000 processes? in one Program. Processes are heavy, use threads instead, though you can't use that many anyway. Make some queues so that if one hangs it doesn't affect the other threads. Maybe you acutally wont to do something completely different, you did't tell what problem you tried to solve with the forks in the first place.

Comment: no, i use `int max_forks = 500;` what would be the limits for threads ? I am trying to check some servers very fast, that is why i use forks. I used before threads, if i do something wrong in a thread, messes up the heap of the whole program, `fork()` is a little bit friendly

Comment: Are you aware that after `fork()`, each process has its very own copy of `num_forks` (and every other variable) and changes made in one are not seen in the others?  You could maybe try to put the variables you want to be shared into a `SHARED` data section of a DLL, or use shared memory, or any other IPC mechanism.  If using shared memory or shared DLL sections, make sure to use `InterlockedIncrement` and `InterlockedDecrement` to change the variable.

Comment: thank you for the hint, any example you would recommend me ? also i did the exactly same thing in PHP and it works ok see here : https://pastecode.xyz/view/07202859 <- this is what i want, thank you again

Comment: You can use a little trick `GNU Make` uses for the job server.
It consists in opening a pipe at the beginning of the program and inserting "tokens" (bytes, the values don't matter). Before each fork, try to get a token. If you can't, just don't fork and continue working, You need to make it non-blocking. So, use 500 tokens and you're set.

Comment: For anyone having this problem, this is the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912662/getline-is-repeatedly-reading-the-file-when-fork-is-used

Comment: It looks like you're waiting in the child!

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems here:

- You don't check the result of `fork(2)`.  This is by far the most serious problem, as you are doing 100,000 forks.  As your manual page will show, `fork()` returns `0` in the child process, and the child's  pid in the parent, **if `fork()` happens to execute correctly.** But `fork()` in your case will soon give you an error, as you cannot probably start 100,000 simultaneous processes in your system. `fork()` returns `-1` in case of error, and you don't check for it, so once it is unable to generate new processes, you'll end in the `else` part of your `if` command, considering what is an error as a successful command fork in the parent process.  What this can lead is something bad, most probably.
- As you have been told in another answer to your question, you'll receive a lot of repeated output (the buffer contents) if you try to call `exit(3)`, instead of `_exit(2)`, due to `atexit()` functionallyt making it to flush `stdio` buffers int both parent and child.  On terminal output, this doesn't happen (you won't see this), as `stdio` uses line buffering on `stdout` to a terminal, so it flushes buffers before any chance to `fork()`. But only if the output device is a terminal, but not if it is a file (where buffers are flushed only whe buffer is full, or at exit time, then all non-flushed `stdio` buffers are flushed.)  As I assume you are searching in some file, I assume you have redirected your output to a file, so a lot of repeated output is to be expected.
- Also, instead of making a `sleep(10)` call at the end, to wait for child processes to finish, use a loop, `wait(2)`ing for child  processes to terminate, until you get an error from `wait`.  This will mean that you don't have more children alive.
- And this is the most important thing.  All system calls are documented in your online manual pages.  Please, use them, as all of what I have explained is present there.
- A minor issue.  You are using old C library calls to do I/O (`puts` is an example) in C++.  Try to avoid them.  C++ was designed to be able to use all the C language calls, so many of the legacy software is reusable and works in C++.  That's true for many legacy libraries, but `stdio` was superseeded a long time ago with a library (`iostream`) that is far better designed (due to the new object oriented capabilities in the new language, not trying to say that Stroustrup is better than Kernighan or Ritchie, my apologies beforehand) so, using C I/O in C++ is strongly deprecated.

You will see from all these comments, that your solution is not in the way you call `getline()`, as you have serious problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(!(fork()))
    {
        // sleep(3);
        puts(chunk);

        exit(0);
    }
```

This should be `_exit(0);`. Otherwise, you execute the exit handlers multiple times which has unpredictable effects on things like shared file descriptors.

Comment: Consider this a cheap lesson. I've seen this very same mistake cause a horrible bug with incredibly nasty security violations. I can't disclose who I had to explain it to, but let's just say it was one of the least pleasant conversations of my life.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, you won't execute atexit handler multiple times.  You will execute it **once on each process.**  This has the side effect of writing the buffered output multiple times, as the file descriptors are `dup(2)`ed and share the file pointer.  This is probably what is happening, as he has redirected output to a file (because he has 100,000 input lines)  He has indeed to do that, but it is not the only error he has.

Comment: @LuisColorado If a process calls `fork` twice and each forked process calls `exit`, then you will call that original process' at-exit handlers twice. Yes, you will do it once on each process, but `fork` duplicated those handlers.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not a problem, only if you have stdio buffers nonflushed, as they will print each trhe buffer contents (one after the other, as file descriptors are `dup`ed)  This is the reason of the multiple outputs.  But this is not the cause of the other multiple errors in the code.  If he runs his program with a moderate number of forks, and outputting to a terminal, he will not see any duplicated output.  I  have explained this all in my response.